# gnu parallel no dependency between jobs in each division

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Assuming we have the following GNU parallel command:

```
parallel --resume-failed --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -m -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh
```

the first CPU: 1.sh 2.sh

the second CPU:3.sh

Right now if the 1.sh failed, the code will retry 1.sh. If 1.sh still failed, 2.ish won't be executed as well.  I wonder if there is anyway that we run 2.sh first if 1.sh failed, and then re-try 1.sh at the end again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling you really do not want `-m`:

```
$ parallel --dryrun --resume-failed --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -m -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh
sh 1.sh 2.sh
sh 3.sh
```

Is that really what you want run? I.e. having `2.sh` as argument for `1.sh`.

I reckon you want to run this instead:

```
$ parallel --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh
```

If any of these fails, you will resume the failed by:

```
$ parallel --resume-failed --joblog test.log --jobs 2 -k sh ::: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh
```

Comment: thanks for helping @Ole!  I finally have time to revisit this post.